# The multi-part identifier "В.Depo" could not be bound

Tags: sql-server

I have a problem with query, but when i try to run i get the error with identifier bounding error, please help:

```
UPDATE A
SET [Miktar] = B.[Miktar]
FROM [Retail].[dbo].[tb_StokDurum] A INNER JOIN 
 (SELECT DISTINCT [UrunID], SUM([Miktar]*-1) AS [Miktar]
 FROM [Retail].[dbo].[tb_SatisDetay]
 GROUP BY [UrunID]) B
ON (A.UrunID = B.[UrunID] AND В.Depo = (SELECT TOP 1 Depo FROM [Retail].[dbo].[tb_StokDurum] WHERE Depo != 'AZ01' AND Depo != '0'))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doesn't look like you included a column called Depo in your B subquery. Also, you may want to just move that part of the join into the where statement of the subquery:

```
DECLARE @depoValue VARCHAR(123) = (
  SELECT TOP 1 Depo 
  FROM [Retail].[dbo].[tb_StokDurum] 
  WHERE Depo != 'AZ01' AND Depo != '0'
);

UPDATE A
SET [Miktar] = B.[Miktar]
FROM 
  [Retail].[dbo].[tb_StokDurum] A INNER JOIN (

    SELECT [UrunID], SUM([Miktar]*-1) AS [Miktar]
    FROM [Retail].[dbo].[tb_SatisDetay]
    WHERE Depo = @depoValue
    GROUP BY [UrunID]

  ) B
ON 
    A.UrunID = B.[UrunID]
;
```

Comment: Thanks, but this query simply doesn't do anything (0 rows affected)

Comment: If the query ran successfully, but did not update any rows, then the WHERE criteria for @depoValue needs to be adjusted, or Retail.dbo.tb_SatisDetay doesn't have any matching values in the Depo column.

Comment: Thank you, worked like a charm! Edited query (wrong value was selected) and that's it!